# Evaluating the Fractional Logit Model - McFadden's Adjusted R^2

Tags: stata, glm

I am estimating a model where the dependent variable is a fraction (between 0 and 1). I used the commands in Stata 14.1

`glm y x, link(logit) family(binomial) robust nolog`

as well as

`fracreg logit y x, vce(robust)`

Both commands deliver the same results.

Now I want to evaluate the outcome, ideally with McFadden's adjusted r^2. Yet, neither `fitstat` nor `estat gof` seem to work after I run the regressions. I get the error message `fitstat does not work with the last model estimated` and `not available after fracreg r(321)`.

Does any of you know an alternative command for McFadden's adjusted r^2?
Or do I have to use a different evaluation method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To adjust the McFadden's R^2, you just need to subtract the number of predictors from the full model log likelihood in the numerator of the fractional part. The formula is [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/Psuedo_RSquareds.htm). Note that you may get negative values.

Here's how you might do that:

```
set more off
webuse set http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/w
webuse wedderburn, clear 

/* (1) Fracreg Way */
fracreg logit yield i.site i.variety, nolog
di "Fracreg McFadden's Adj. R^2:" %-9.3f 1-(e(ll)-e(k))/(e(ll_0))

/* (2) GLM Way */
glm yield, link(logit) family(binomial) robust nolog // intercept only model
local ll_0 = e(ll)
glm yield i.site i.variety, link(logit) family(binomial) robust nolog // full model
di "McFadden's Adj. R^2: " %-9.3f 1-(e(ll)-e(k))/`ll_0'
```

The GLM R^2 will be slightly different because the maximization algorithm is different and so the likelihoods will be different as well. I am not sure how to tweak the ML options so they match exactly.

You can verify that we did things correctly with a command where fitstat works:

```
sysuse auto, clear
logit foreign price mpg
fitstat
di "McFadden's Adj. R^2: " %-9.3f 1-(e(ll)-e(k))/(e(ll_0))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dimitriy!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the pseudo-R-squared that appears in the `fracreg` output is  McFadden's pseudo R squared. I'm not sure if this is the same as the  McFadden's *adjusted* r^2 that you mention.

You can see it is McFadden's pseudo-R-squared from investigating the `maximize` command as suggested by @nick-cox's [post on Stata.com](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/r-squared/). In the reference manual for `maximize`, page 1478 (Stata 14) it says:

> Let L1 be the log likelihood of the full model (that is, the log-likelihood value shown on the output), and let L0 be the log likelihood of the “constant-only” model. ... The pseudo-R2 (McFadden 1974) is defined as 1 - L1 / L0. This is simply the log likelihood on a scale where 0 corresponds to the “constant-only” model and 1 corresponds to perfect prediction for a discrete model (in which case the overall log likelihood is 0).

If this is what you are looking for, this value may be pulled out using

```
fracreg logit y x, vce(robust)
scalar myRsquared =  e(r2_p)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Imo.
I am still searching for McFadden's Adjusted R^2 though, in order to account for the large amount (14) of explanatory variables in the model.